# EditText text edit (typing , deleting) is propagated to layouts under the top layout instead to own layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have the following layout which is displayed above all other apps using window manager.

Where the AppCompatEditText part is commented by:

text edit (typing , deleting) is propagated to layouts under the layout which contains the EditText instead to own layout.

The question is: How to propagate the EditText event correctly to get the ability to edit text in Edit text component instead of propagating events down to bottom layer under top window?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout android:id="@+id/sample1"
                                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- BOTTOM VIEW LEFT-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cdb70d0d"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <!--What you want to show-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/closeResultBubble"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/swipe_to_close"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- SURFACE VIEW START - MAIN VISIBLE CONTENT (SHOWN BY DEFAULT) -->
    <phonetoaster.com.bubbletranslate.activity.TouchableLinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/AUTO"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

        <!--HEADING WITH ICON BUTTONS-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <!--HEADING WITH ICON BUTTONS-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@color/main_blue"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/settingsButtonTop"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/settings"
                    android:src="@drawable/settings"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closeButtonTop"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/close"
                    android:src="@drawable/close"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--RESULT-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <!--ORIGINAL PART-->

                <!--ORIGINAL SETTINGS BAR-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/original_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewOriginalTextSelectedLanguage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="@string/original"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/source_lang_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/main_blue"
                        android:gravity="start"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--ORIGINAL TEXT-->
                <!-- THIS EDITTEXT CANNOT BE EDITED -->

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextSourceText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:text="@string/lipsum"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollViewSource"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">


                    <!--
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSourceText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:text="@string/lipsum"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>
                        -->
                </ScrollView>


                <!--HORIZONTAL RULE-->
                <View style="@style/Divider"/>

                <!--TRANSLATION PART-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/translated_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <!--LANG BAR-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="@string/original"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/translation_lang_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/main_blue"
                        android:gravity="start"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--TRANSLATED TEXT-->
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollViewResult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewTranslatedText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:text="@string/lipsum"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--COPY TRANSLATION BTN-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

              <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                  android:id="@+id/copyTranslationButton"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:background="@color/main_blue"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="@string/copy_to_clipboard"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Surface View End -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </phonetoaster.com.bubbletranslate.activity.TouchableLinearLayout>

    <!-- Surface View End -->
</com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```